# How to grep line after pattern match only for one pattern out of many

Tags: linux, grep, match

I have a data file something like following. I want to grep "PANIC:", "Node 0/1/2/3:" and blank lines, but want to include next line ( "-A1" option ) only to one pattern - "PANIC:", not others. How to do that.

Kindly help to find solution

```
# cat data.txt
Node 0:
    DATE: 2020-12-19 04:06:44
    DATE: 2020-12-19 07:02:54
    PANIC: ABC
    DATE: 2020-12-19 20:02:54
    DATE: 2020-12-18 21:25:39

Node 1:
    DATE: 2020-12-20 09:35:43
    DATE: 2020-12-20 12:12:29

Node 2:
    

Node 3:
    DATE: 2020-12-19 20:03:00
    DATE: 2020-12-19 15:35:09
    PANIC: XYZ
    DATE: 2020-12-19 06:44:27
#
# cat data.txt | grep -A1 --no-group-separator -e PANIC: -e 'Node [0-7]:' -e ^$
Node 0:
    DATE: 2020-12-19 04:06:44
    PANIC: ABC
    DATE: 2020-12-19 20:02:54

Node 1:
    DATE: 2020-12-20 09:35:43

Node 2:
    DATE: 2020-12-20 03:00:15

Node 3:
    DATE: 2020-12-19 20:03:00
    PANIC: XYZ
    DATE: 2020-12-19 06:44:27
#
```

Expected filtered data is something like this

```
Node 0:
    PANIC: ABC
    DATE: 2020-12-19 20:02:54

Node 1:

Node 2:

Node 3:
    PANIC: XYZ
    DATE: 2020-12-19 06:44:27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as you ask with:

```
awk '/PANIC:/{print; getline; print} /Node [0-7]/ || /^ *$/' input
```

Although you don't mention it in the question, your sample output demonstrates that you also want to combine multiple blank lines in a single blank line.  That can be done with:

```
awk '/./{a=0} /PANIC:/{print; getline; print} /^ *$/ && !a++{print} /Node [0-7]/' input
```

To print the line before the PANIC match, it's probably easiest to simply record the previous line.  Something like:

```
 awk '/PANIC:/{print prev; print; getline; print} { prev = $0 } /Node [0-7]/ || /^ *$/' input | perl -00pe1
```

Comment: Great William. Thanks for quick response. Just a quick question, what if, I had to include previous line ( grep's "-B1" option ) to the pattern - "PANIC:" - I need to write another script for this.

Comment: Pre-matching is a bit of a hassle, but not too bad.  Just store the previous line in a variable and print it as needed.  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk  -F: ' /Node|PANIC/ { print; if($1~/PANIC/) { getline; print}  } ' data.txt
```

Results:

```
$ awk  -F: ' /Node|PANIC/ { print; if($1~/PANIC/) { getline; print}  } ' susanta.txt
Node 0:
    PANIC: ABC
    DATE: 2020-12-19 20:02:54
Node 1:
Node 2:
Node 3:
    PANIC: XYZ
    DATE: 2020-12-19 06:44:27
$
```